# User event script not getting trigged which is deployed on a entity record

Tags: triggers, mapreduce, netsuite, user-event

I have created a user event script which is deployed on the vendor record.
There is another map reduce script which is creating the vendor record.
The user event script is working fine from UI, but when themap-reduce is triggered to create a vendor, the user event script is not working

I have my logic in before submit and after submit event of the user event

Comment: could you post the script?

Comment: I couldn't share the code but, my map reduce script has the logic to create a vendor, vendor is getting created but the user event is not getting triggered, once the record is created when I edit and save the record user event is getting triggered

Comment: most likely it's an issue with either the deployment, or the UE script itself, namely it's "comment headers" (I experienced something like this). So at least show a screen shot of the deployement page and the beginning of your UE script, namely up to the line with the define() call

Comment: otherwise, probably, you should look into the deployment, if it has all the rights etc.

Comment: Thanks the issue was with the deployment setting user has restricted to few child subsidiaries but forgot to include the parent subsidiary